# Model for nuclear stability from QCD

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

In most nuclear physics  books the models that maintain the nucleus stable ,that do not come from QCD.

Is there any model that comes from QCD that explains why atomic nucleus are stable?

Comment: Any "model that comes from QCD" that isn't just QCD is, by definition, phenomenological.

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear on when a model "comes from QCD". For example, does chiral perturbation theory come from QCD? What about the MIT bag model?